# Virtual COM port works in PuTTy but not in my program

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

When I connect a device to the computer using USB virtual COM port and open the port in my application (in Qt, QSerialPort), it receives nothing.

When I open the port in PuTTy, it works as expected.

Surprisingly, after closing PuTTy and opening the port in my application again, it started to work as expected.

This problem only occurs with some devices, namely Raspberry Pi Pico, but not with other devices like STM32 USB VCP and USB-UART transceivers.

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause is that the USB device needs to have the DTR signal (which is part of RS232) set to high in order to start transmitting. (many devices disregard the value of DTR, some do not)

Use `serial->setDataTerminalReady(true);` on `QSerialPort` **after** opening it.

PuTTy seems to set it to high after opening, but not set it low on closing. That's why it makes it work in your app after opening it once.